# cudaMemset line number

Tags: cuda, nsight

I wrote a CUDA application. My application calls a kernel around 40 times. After profiling it, after every kernel finishes it's execution, there is one `cudaMemset()`. And these cudaMemsets are consuming lot of time. However, I don't have any `cudaMemset` in my `.cu` file. Does CUDA APIs internally calls `cudaMemset`? and also is there any way to know line number in CUDA profiler?

Comment: Can you show some code? Or list the CUDA runtime functions you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Nsight Visual Studio Edition Trace Activity supports capturing call stacks on all CUDA Runtime and CUDA Driver API calls.

**Enabling Callstack Trace for CUDA Runtime API Calls**

1. In the **Nsight** menu execute **Start Performance Analysis**.
   (**New Analysis Activity** in Nsight < 3)
2. In the Activity Editor expand the Trace Settings section and the CUDA section.
3. In the CUDA section next to **Runtime API Trace** set **Call Stack Trace** to **Always**.
4. Run the Analysis Activity.

**Viewing the Callstack Trace for a CUDA Runtime API Call**

1. In the captured Analysis Report click on the Report Page selector in the top left and select the page **CUDA Runtime API Calls**.
2. In the table click on the API call of interest.
3. In the correlation pane tree in the bottom left of the report page click on **Stack Trace**.

The above process can be done for other API domains. The correlation pane can also be used to determine the API call and callstack that generate a kernel launch or memory copy.

[image: Nsight Visual Studio Edition 3.0 RC1 Analysis Report showing Call Stack Trace]

Comment: Thanks Greg, but sadly I am on Linux and NSIGHT is broken so Is there any command line tool for that?NVPROF?

Comment: On Linux I would recommend running the program under cuda-gdb (can use Nsight Eclipse Edition). Add a CPU instruction breakpoint on cudaMemset and look at the call stack. The Visual Profiler and nvprof do not currently support collecting stack traces on API calls.